# Cache not found because action searches for "<key>, <key>", not just "<key>"

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to restore from a cache. My job reads:

```
  testing-windows:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        example: [Frank2Example1, Frank2Example2, Frank2Example3]
    name: Test windows ${{ matrix.example }}
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Cache Frank!Runner dependencies - build
      uses: actions/cache@v2
      with:
        path: build
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-frank-runner-build
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-frank-runner-build
    - name: Cache Frank!Runner dependencies - download
      uses: actions/cache@v2
      with:
        path: download
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-frank-runner-download
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-frank-runner-download
... Other steps ...
```

Step `Cache Frank!Runner dependencies - build` does not find its cache. The output reads:

```
Run actions/cache@v2
  with:
    path: build
    key: Windows-frank-runner-build
    restore-keys: Windows-frank-runner-build
  
Cache not found for input keys: Windows-frank-runner-build, Windows-frank-runner-build
```

In this message, the key is duplicated.

This issue does not apply to the next step: `Cache Frank!Runner dependencies - download`. That step can find its cache.

I tried running this job multiple times. It succeeds, but the cache remains unavailable as mentioned.

My full code is available at https://github.com/mhdirkse/frank-runner, commit SHA ad4644d1ab6b7389294a6ad3d2c67c9655517fa6.
Did I do something wrong or is this a bug in GitHub actions?

EDIT:

As you see in the text, this failure happens on Windows. I am doing the same under Ubuntu, but then there is no error. Both caches work properly under Linux.

EDIT Thursday Agust 11 2022

I am having the same issue under Ubuntu now. On https://github.com/ibissource/frank-manual commit `57b4c937559d20c5420245b3f0c07fa79366c9c6`, I have the following GitHub action YAML:

```
name: TestFrankRunner.
on:
  push:
    paths: srcSteps/Frank2Webapp/**
  pull_request:
    paths: srcSteps/Frank2Webapp/**
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  test-frank2webapp:
    name: Test Frank2Webapp
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Show input
      run: echo ${{ github.event.inputs.forceLatestFF }}
    - name: Cache Maven downloads
      uses: actions/cache@v2
      with:
        path: ~/.m2/repository/
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-maven
        restore-keys: |
          Linux-maven
    - name: Start Frank2Webapp
      run: mvn --log-file log.txt clean install jetty:run &
      working-directory: srcSteps/Frank2Webapp/v520
...
Other steps
...
```

My GitHub action log shows the line:

```
Cache not found for input keys: Linux-maven, Linux-maven
```

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, but I think it's worth pointing out that mine fails on `macos-10.15` while working correctly on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem for the example of the `frank-manual` repository, see EDIT of August 11 2022. In the `frank-manual` repository, I simply upgraded to `actions/cache@v3`.

In the release notes of v3, I saw the following:

> Fixed tar creation error while trying to create tar with path as ~/ home folder on ubuntu-latest.

Indeed, I was caching directory `~/.m2/repository/` so the fix applies to my test.

I am not sure about the original question that was about the Windows operating system. I hope to inform about that later.

EDIT September 5 2022

The original issue has not been fixed. In project https://github.com/ibissource/frank-runner/, all usages of the cache action have been updated to v3. Nevertheless, step `Cache Frank!Runner dependencies - build` cannot restore its cache. This problem happens under Windows, no more under Linux.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, the second key is the restore key. In your case, both the key and the restore are the same. The restore key is basically a fallback mechanism in case there is no match/hit for the given key.
So the problem is not because action searches for ", ", the problem lies somewhere else.